# Run jobs parallel in oracle

Tags: multithreading, oracle, plsql, parallel-processing

I have 8 jobs which I have to run. At any instance, there must be 4 jobs running. One of the sample jobs is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE job1
AS
  vblSQL  VARCHAR(32767);
  vJobID  NUMBER:=1;

BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE'insert into job_logs values('''||vJobID||''',sysdate,NULL)';
  vblSQL:= 'UPDATE jobs SET status=''R'' WHERE job_ID=1';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(vblSQL);
  Dbms_Lock.sleep(45);
  vblSQL:= 'UPDATE jobs SET status=''Y'' WHERE job_ID=1';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(vblSQL);
  vblSQL:= 'UPDATE job_logs SET endtime=SYSDATE WHERE jobID=1';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(vblSQL);
END;
```

Other 7 jobs are similar to this only varying in the `Job_ID`. I have written a code  which initializes four jobs to run at once. Here is the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_ProcessJobs
AS
  vblSQL          VARCHAR2(32767);
  vblTotalJobs    VARCHAR2(1000);
  vblRemJobs      VARCHAR2(1000);
  vblJob1         VARCHAR2(1000);
  vblJob2         VARCHAR2(1000);
  vblJob3         VARCHAR2(1000);
  vblJob4         VARCHAR2(1000);
  vblJob          VARCHAR2(1000);
  lno             NUMBER;

BEGIN
  SELECT Count(*) INTO vblTotalJobs FROM jobs WHERE status='N';

  FOR i IN 1..4 LOOP
      SELECT jobname INTO vblJob 
      FROM 
       (SELECT job_id,status,jobname,Rank() OVER (ORDER by job_id)rnk
        FROM
         (SELECT * from jobs WHERE status='N' ORDER BY job_id)
      )WHERE rnk=i; 

    IF    i=1 THEN vbljob1:=vbljob;
    ELSIF i=2 THEN vbljob2:=vbljob;
    ELSIF i=3 THEN vbljob3:=vbljob;
    ELSIF i=4 THEN vbljob4:=vbljob;
    END IF;

  END LOOP;

  Dbms_Job.submit(lno,'BEGIN '||vbljob1||'; END;');
  COMMIT;
  Dbms_Job.submit(lno,'BEGIN '||vbljob2||'; END;');
  COMMIT;
  Dbms_Job.submit(lno,'BEGIN '||vbljob3||'; END;');
  COMMIT;
  Dbms_Job.submit(lno,'BEGIN '||vbljob4||'; END;');
  COMMIT;

  Dbms_Output.put_line(vblTotalJobs);

END;
```

This allows me to run four jobs parallel at once. Now what should I do to run another job(say Job no. 5) as soon as one job is completed and so on. Every time I try to do it, the program enters an infinite loop and I have to kill the session to stop it.

What I am trying to achieve is similar to threading in JAVA or other programming languages. Any help would be highly appreciated.

I am using Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to run parallel jobs you should consider DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE it gives you more control over jobs.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_parallel_ex.htm#ARPLS233

Answer (score 0):

Please check if **JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES** caters your requirement? You can define range as 4.

For more info you can check this site - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams102.htm